# How do I configure existing Postfix server to use external Spamassassin server?

Tags: postfix

I have an existing Postfix server using greylisting, and need to utilize an external, existing Spamassassin server which is managed by someone else. How can I configure that? I am thinking I would use spamc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with creating my own content filter and butchered the example script [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_spamassassin.html)

The difference between the above example script and what I wanted to achieve was that I only wanted spamassassin to give me a spam score, by using the following

```
spamc -d 10.10.10.50 -p783 -c < [mail msg]
```

where

-d is the spamassassin host

-p is the tcp port

-c 'check only'

spamc can be installed by using `apt-get install spamc`